# Text won't stop running off the page

Tags: css

I am trying to create a type writer animation with CSS, but am having trouble with the text running off the page. I am trying to make the animation go across several lines as it approaches the end of the screen, but everything I've looked up doesn't seem to work. Here is my code:

```css
h1 {
  color: black;
  font-family: palatino;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.write {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 100 100 100 100;
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end);
  word-break: break-all;
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="write"> Make this several lines!</h1>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Getting a proper typewriter effect with just CSS is problematic as each line can have a different number of characters in it depending on the viewport or other settings. A full solution probably needs Javascript which can work out how much to move to reveal a character, or just put characters into the element one by one on a timeout.

Comment: If I have understood, you want the animation to go line by line with delay after typing animation on each line right?